# LS command without using system calls in PHP

Tags: ls

Hi I want to know how to write the `ls` command using PHP, I am not looking for system calls

`( $last_line = system('ls -l', $retval) )`

but own implementation of `ls` command ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `glob` function.
See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) for many examples.

Answer (score 1):

See the [readdir](http://php.net/readdir) examples. It shows how to list directories and files, then you have to get their [permissions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php), [owner](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileowner.php) or other attributes like [modification time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php). Follow the list of [filesystem functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) and you'll find everything you need

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to implement it? There are already Legacy PHP commands.

```
array scandir ( string $directory [, int $sorting_order = SCANDIR_SORT_ASCENDING [, resource $context ]] )
```

Or

```
string readdir ([ resource $dir_handle ] )
```

Examples can be found in on the [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) website

Comment: What is the result you expect? An array of files, an array of array of files, size, rights ?

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite the code? Optimisation? See how it works? Your company asked you?